# Bind Data not shown in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, winforms, windows-forms-designer

In the below code, I am successfully getting 369 records in the options list:

```
  public ArrayList GetOptionsChain(string ticker)
{
    ticker = CorrectSymbol(ticker);
    string url;
    if (ticker.StartsWith("^"))
        url = string.Format(@"http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol={0}&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-", ticker.TrimStart(new char[] { '^' }));
    else
        url = string.Format(@"http://npg.veh.mybluehostin.me:8000/symbols/?name={0}", ticker.TrimStart(new char[] { '^' }));

    ArrayList options_list = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(url);

        var nodes1 = (from n in xml.Descendants("oc").Descendants("row")
                      select new
                      {
                          type = (string)n.Element("type").Value,
                          symbol = (string)n.Element("symbol").Value,
                          expiration = (string)n.Element("expiration").Value,
                          strike = (string)n.Element("strike").Value,
                          bid = (string)n.Element("bid").Value,
                          ask = (string)n.Element("ask").Value,
                          last = (string)n.Element("last").Value,
                          change = (string)n.Element("change").Value,
                          totalvol = (string)n.Element("totalvol").Value,
                          open_int = (string)n.Element("open_int").Value,
                          chng_open_int = (string)n.Element("chng_open_int").Value
                      }).ToList();




        foreach (var n in nodes1)
        {
            Option option = new Option();

            // option stock ticker and number of stocks per contract
            option.stock = ticker;
            option.stocks_per_contract = 1;
            option.update_timestamp = DateTime.Now;
            option.type = n.type;
            // symbol
            option.symbol = n.symbol; //"." + symbol_href.Replace("javascript:chartPopup(", "").Replace(");", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("'", "");

            // expiration date
            DateTime.TryParse(n.expiration, ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out option.expiration);

            // strike price
            double.TryParse(n.strike, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.strike);

            // option bid price                    
            option.price.bid = double.NaN;
            double.TryParse(n.bid, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.price.bid);

            // option ask price

            option.price.ask = double.NaN;
            double.TryParse(n.ask, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.price.ask);

            // option last price

            option.price.last = double.NaN;
            double.TryParse(n.last, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.price.last);

            // option price change

            option.price.change = double.NaN;
            double.TryParse(n.change, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.price.change);

            // option volume

            option.volume.total = 0;
            double.TryParse(n.totalvol, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.volume.total);

            // open int

            option.open_int = 0;
            int.TryParse(n.open_int, NumberStyles.Number, ci, out option.open_int);

            options_list.Add(option);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return options_list;

}
```

But, it won't load the data on grid. The below code is used to show data on screen:

```
private void UpdateOptionsTable(string stock, Quote quote)
    { 
        // get stock's option list
        ArrayList list = Comm.Server.GetOptionsChain(stock);
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return;

        // begin data load
        OptionsTable.BeginLoadData();

        try
        {
            foreach (Option option in list)
            {
                // update time-value
                if (quote != null) option.price.timevalue = Algo.Model.TimeValue(quote.price.last, option);

                // add option to table
                AddOptionEntry(quote, option);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        // end data load
        OptionsTable.EndLoadData();
    }
```

This is the addoptionentry definition:

```
private OptionsTableRow GetOptionsTableRow()
    {
        if(OptionsTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            OptionsTableRow row = OptionsTable.NewOptionsTableRow();
            OptionsTable.Rows.Add(row);
            row.AcceptChanges();
        }

        return (OptionsTableRow)OptionsTable.Rows[0];
    }
private void AddOptionEntry(Quote quote, Option option)
    {
        bool new_row = false;
        OptionsTableRow row = GetOptionsTableRow();

        // make sure the option is in the future
        //if (option.expiration > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)) return;

        if (!OptionsTable.Rows.Contains(option.symbol))
        {
            row = GetOptionsTableRow();
            new_row = true;

            try
            {
                row.Symbol = option.symbol;
            }
            catch { }
        }
        else
        {
            row = OptionsTable.FindBySymbol(option.symbol);
            row.BeginEdit();
        }

        try
        {
            row.Type = option.type;
            row.Strike = option.strike;
            row.Expiration = DateTime.Parse(option.expiration.ToShortDateString());

            if (!double.IsNaN(option.price.last)) row.Last = option.price.last;
            else row.SetLastNull();

            if (!double.IsNaN(option.price.change)) row.Change = option.price.change;
            else row.SetChangeNull();

            if (!double.IsNaN(option.price.timevalue)) row.TimeValue = option.price.timevalue;
            else row.SetTimeValueNull();

            if (!double.IsNaN(option.price.bid)) row.Bid = option.price.bid;
            else row.SetBidNull();

            if (!double.IsNaN(option.price.ask)) row.Ask = option.price.ask;
            else row.SetAskNull();

            row.Volume = option.volume.total;
            row.OpenInt = option.open_int;
            row.Stock = option.stock;
            row.UpdateTimeStamp = option.update_timestamp;
            row.StocksPerContract = option.stocks_per_contract;

            if (option.type == "Call")
            {
                if (option.strike > quote.price.last * 1.02) row.TheMoney = "OTM";
                else if (option.strike < quote.price.last * 0.98) row.TheMoney = "ITM";
                else if (option.strike == quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM";
                else if (option.strike > quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM,OTM";
                else if (option.strike < quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM,ITM";
            }
            else
            {
                if (option.strike > quote.price.last * 1.02) row.TheMoney = "ITM";
                else if (option.strike < quote.price.last * 0.98) row.TheMoney = "OTM";
                else if (option.strike == quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM";
                else if (option.strike > quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM,ITM";
                else if (option.strike < quote.price.last) row.TheMoney = "ATM,OTM";
            }

            option.greeks = Algo.Model.Greeks(quote, option, Config.Local.FederalIterest, StockDividendRate, double.NaN, double.NaN);

            row.ImpliedVolatility = option.greeks.implied_volatility;
            row.Delta = option.greeks.delta;
            row.Gamma = option.greeks.gamma;
            row.Vega = option.greeks.vega;
            row.Theta = option.greeks.theta;
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            // add row to table (if new)
            if (new_row) OptionsTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        catch { }

        // save option in cache
        if (option_cache.ContainsKey(option.symbol)) option_cache[option.symbol] = option;
        else option_cache.Add(option.symbol, option);
    }
```

This is where I am calling updateoptionstable:

```
public void Update(string stock)
    {
        // update quote table
        Quote quote = null;

        try
        {
            // update quote data base
            quote = UpdateQuotesTable(stock);
        }
        catch { }

        if (quote != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // update database version and creation date
                Version = Config.Local.CurrentVersion;
                DatabaseCreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

                // update options table
                UpdateOptionsTable(quote.stock, quote);

                // update conversion tables
                UpdateConversionTables();

                // update historical volatility              
                if ((Config.Local.GetParameter("Volatility Mode") == "Stock HV") ||
                    (Config.Local.GetParameter("Download Historical Volatility") == "Yes"))
                {
                    UpdateHistoricalVolatility(quote.stock);
                }

                // update derived data
                UpdateDerivedData(quote, true, true, true, true);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

and in the end the update function is used  by :

```
private void downloadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // update stock data
        core.Update(stockText.Text);

        // update interset rate if (auto update is enabled)
        if (Config.Local.GetParameter("Federal Interest Auto Update") == "Enabled")
        {
            Config.Local.SetInterest("Federal", Comm.Server.GetAnnualInterestRate(1.0));
        }
    }
```

Rest of the things is being shown in the grid but neither I am getting any error nor this data was able to populate on the screen. Can someone please review and correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

These are the datatable and bindingsource I am using in the code:

```
    //Initialize Components

this.optionsTableBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);


((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.optionsDataGridView)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.optionsTableBindingSource)).BeginInit();
            this.optionSelectionGroupBox1.SuspendLayout();
            this.optionSelectionGroupBox3.SuspendLayout();
            this.optionSelectionGroupBox2.SuspendLayout();
            this.optionSelectionGroupBox4.SuspendLayout();
            this.stockGroupBox.SuspendLayout();


            this.optionsDataGridView.DataSource = this.optionsTableBindingSource;
// optionsTableBindingSource
            // 
            this.optionsTableBindingSource.DataMember = "OptionsTable";
            this.optionsTableBindingSource.DataSource = this.optionsSet;
#MainForms
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.optionsDataGridView)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.optionsTableBindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.optionSelectionGroupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.optionSelectionGroupBox3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.optionSelectionGroupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.optionSelectionGroupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.stockGroupBox.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.stockGroupBox.PerformLayout();
```

and this is how updatebuttonclick event works:

```
private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // execute only once
        if (downloadWorker.IsBusy) return;

        // clear database if symbol is new
        if (updateButton.Text == "Update") newButton_Click(sender, e);

        // show download message
        updateButton.Visible = false;
        autoRefreshCheckBox.Visible = false;
        serverProgressBar.Value = 0;
        serverProgressBar.Visible = false;
        progressLabel.Visible = false;
        downloadLabel.Visible = true;            

        // control tour progress
        if (balloonForm.Active) balloonForm.Hide();

        // suspend binding
        optionsTableBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        optionsTableBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; 

        positionsTableBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        positionsTableBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; 

        resultsTableBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        resultsTableBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; 

        // run worker
        downloadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: you have `asp.net` and also `winforms` in  your tags. When you tag winforms I am thinking about a DataGrid and a bindingsource, is that what you have ? Or do you have an asp.net table ?

Comment: @GuidoG Sorry for not including those things. I am using Datagrid and bindingsource and I have been updated the code for the same. Also, I have made some changes in addoptionentry function which helps me in getting only one row display in the grid. I am new in this technology so sorry for the convenience.

Comment: I see `SuspendBinding()` in your code but I cant see any `ResumeBinding()` ?